# how to print object's properties after matching with one of its property

Tags: javascript

I want to match with one of the object's property values and if it matches that property I need to print all other properties of that object.
I am trying to match the firstName property and print its remaining.

here is the code

```
      var friends=new Object();
  friends.steve={
  firstName:"Steve",
  lastName:"smith",
  number:"8861785484",
  address:['rajajinagar','bangalore','560010']
  };

friends.bill={
firstName:"Bill",
lastName:"gates",
number:"9845378136",
address:['shivajinagar','bangalore','560018']
};


var search=function(name){
    for(firstName in friends){
        if(friends[name].firtstName===name){
            console.log(friends[name]);
            return (friends[name]);
            
            }
        
        
        }
    
    }
 search("steve");
```

output should be all the properties of "steve" object like.. firstName, lastName, number and address

Comment: `steve` should match `Steve`? or you could access `friends.steve` directly.

Comment: friends[name].firtstName ???

Comment: What is your question? Is there an issue with your code? Why do you have  `for(firstName in friends){}` in your code but are not using `firstName` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

make friends an array of objects, instead of an object of objects, and then try this:

```
for(var i = 0;i<friends.length;i++){
    if(friends[i].firstName===name){
        console.log(friends[i]);
        return friends[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: also, you have friends[name].firtstName instead of "firstName", and also also "steve" != "Steve"

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over the properties (use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) and check if `firstName` is equal to `name`. This proposal looks for all steves.

The variable `k` indicates a property name of the object, like `'steve'` or `'bill'`.

```js
var friends = { steve: { firstName: "Steve", lastName: "smith", number: "8861785484", address: ['rajajinagar', 'bangalore', '560010'] }, bill: { firstName: "Bill", lastName: "gates", number: "9845378136", address: ['shivajinagar', 'bangalore', '560018'] } },
    search = function (name) {
        Object.keys(friends).forEach(function (k) {
            if (friends[k].firstName.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) {
                console.log(friends[k]);
            }
        });
    };

search("steve");
```

A proposal with a [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

```js
var friends = { steve: { firstName: "Steve", lastName: "smith", number: "8861785484", address: ['rajajinagar', 'bangalore', '560010'] }, bill: { firstName: "Bill", lastName: "gates", number: "9845378136", address: ['shivajinagar', 'bangalore', '560018'] } },
    search = function (name) {
        for (k in friends) {
            if (friends[k].firstName.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) {
                console.log(friends[k]);
            }
        };
    };

search("steve");
```

Comment: i'm allowed to use only for in loop

Comment: since i'm new to javascript..so..what's "K" here? is it pointing to object properties?

Comment: @Nag, plese see addtional information above. the variable `k` holds in both cases the property name steve, bill of the friends object.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this;

```js
var friends = new Object(),
  getDetail = n => friends[n.toLowerCase()];
friends.steve={
  firstName:"Steve",
  lastName:"smith",
  number:"8861785484",
  address:['rajajinagar','bangalore','560010']
  };

friends.bill={
  firstName:"Bill",
  lastName:"gates",
  number:"9845378136",
  address:['shivajinagar','bangalore','560018']
};
console.log(getDetail("Steve"));
```

might do like this;